# Is wx.lib.wxcairo compatible with PyQt 5

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, deprecated, pycairo

## How do I fix this error?

I'm trying to fix python code I didn't write. This error has been taking up a longer portion of my life than it should:

```
File "/home/hawk/final_project_ws/src/final-project-group-4-inc/src/xdot_k/xdot_qt.py", line 173, in draw
    painter.setPen(QColor.fromRgbF(*pen.fillcolor))
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'setPen'
```

I know whats causing the error. it tries to call a Qpainter function with a wx.lib.wxcairo. I don't know how to fix it though. This code spans 4 other files and they seem to be used as though the author knew that these errors would never pop up but now it seems as though I have to use one or the other and I can't figure out how to to switch it to one or the other. is there a function that make them compatible with each other? Here is the call to setPen(). `painter.setPen(QColor.fromRgbF(*pen.fillcolor))` So painter is the main offender because in this code its passed as a `cairo.context` object when its called instead of a Qpainter.  Bellow is the function that causes the error:

```
def OnPaint(self, event):
    """Redraw the graph."""
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)

    #print dc
    ctx = wxcairo.ContextFromDC(dc)
    # ctx = pangocairo.CairoContext(ctx)

    #print "DRAW"

    # Get widget size
    width, height = self.GetSize()
    #width,height = self.dc.GetSizeTuple()

    ctx.rectangle(0,0,width,height)
    ctx.clip()

    ctx.set_source_rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    ctx.paint()

    ctx.save()
    ctx.translate(0.5*width, 0.5*height)

    ctx.scale(self.zoom_ratio, self.zoom_ratio)
    ctx.translate(-self.x, -self.y)

    """
    ctx is a cairo.context object initialized above that is being passed instead of a          
    Qpainter object which is causing my error.
    """

    self.graph.draw(ctx, highlight_items=self.highlight) #This is where ctx is passed.

    ctx.restore()

    self.drag_action.draw(ctx)
```

## What would help?

1. A function I can call that converts ctx into a Qpainter object.
2. A conversion of this code so that it uses only the Qpainter class instead of wxcairo.
3. A clarificaition as to why wx.lib.wxcairo might be used together. I know this code was written in python2 if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Qt and cairo are not (directly) compatible. There were attempts to make cairo usable with Qt, but support has been removed more than 10 years ago. Note that it seems that you're trying to use very basic primitive functions, which are already available for QPainter: see [`drawRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawRect), [`scale()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#scale) and [`translate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#translate). It's a bit difficult to help you more on this, as it's not clear what calls `OnPaint()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  OnPaint is only called once in the entire package and its by this line of code: `self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)` Which is within a constructor for a class called WxDotWindow(wx.Panel) which brings up other questions I have if I were to change this specific function use QPainter.  What is a wx.Panel?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm gonna try those changes with the function but from seeing how often wx is used it might be better to just rewrite everything but I'll be sure to update this post if I find a solution.

Comment: That bind doesn't mean that it's being called only once, but that it's called *every time* a paint event occurs. A wx.Panel is the "container" inside a window on which controls are placed (similar to QWidget in Qt). Now, what's not clear to me is why you're trying to use Qt (what is `graph`?) with a wx based program?

Comment: So I got the code to stop giving me errors by translating some of it so that it uses QPainter but now its saying `QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active` and I don't know how to activate the QPainter.